# How to center group of elements within div

Tags: html, css, centering, absolute

I'm creating a banner for a website.  I'm stubbornly trying to do it with HTML5/CSS3 rather than making an image.  The banner has an opaque background image that spans the entire width of the page wrapper (set to 80% screen width).  Over that I have three elements: a logo and two lines of text.  I have placed the three where I want them my making them absolute and using top, left, etc.  I also placed these three elements in their own div.  I would like to center them over the background image.  I've tried setting auto margins on either side (the preferred way in css3, but it's not working.

Actually, it would also be great to be able to not only center the group of three (logo, line 1, line 2) but to be able to move them around together as an absolute element.  Is that possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/965Mj/1/

***   HTML   *****

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div id="background-image"></div>
        <div id="header-group">
            <img id="house-logo" src="http://arielbalter.com/cio/img/CheckItOutHouseNoBackground.png " />
             <h1 id="line1">check it out!</h1>

             <h1 id="line2">Home Inspection</h1>

        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

*** CSS ***

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: Wheat;
    width: 1280px;
    /* doing that because jsfiddle viewport is not the entire page width.*/
    /* in real life, the wrapper extends below the banner -- that is where the main part of the website is */
}
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: White;
}
header #background-image {
    background-image: url("http://arielbalter.com/cio/img/3tab_slanted.jpg");
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#header-group {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
#house-logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    top:10px;
    left: 10px;
}
#line1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    top: -15px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family:"KGLoveSomebody", "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
    font-size: 7em;
    color: FireBrick;
}
#line2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 185px;
    bottom: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:"Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#wrapper {
background-color: Wheat;
width: 1280px;
/* doing that because jsfiddle viewport is not the entire page width.*/
/* in real life, the wrapper extends below the banner -- that is where the main part of the website is */
}
header {

width: 100%;
height: 180px;
background-color: White;
margin:0 auto;
}
header #background-image {
background-image: url("http://arielbalter.com/cio/img/3tab_slanted.jpg");
text-align: center;
 display: table;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
opacity: 0.3;
}

#house-logo {
 display: table;
float: left;
height: 160px;
padding-left: 10em;


}
#line1 {
display: table;

text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family:"KGLoveSomebody", "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
font-size: 7em;
color: FireBrick;
}
 #line2 {



    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 6em;
    font-family:"Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

AND

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
    <div id="background-image">

 <img id="house-logo" src="http://arielbalter.com/cio/img/CheckItOutHouseNoBackground.png " />
         <h1 id="line1">check it out!</h1>

         <h1 id="line2">Home Inspection</h1>

    </div>
</header>
</div>
```

/////////////////// EDIT GEARED TOWARDS COMMENT //////////////////

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div id="background-image"></div>
        <div id="header-group" >
            <img id="house-logo" src="http://arielbalter.com/cio/img/CheckItOutHouseNoBackground.png " />
             <h1 id="line1">check it out!</h1>

             <h1 id="line2">Home Inspection</h1>

        </div>
    </header>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

AND .......

```
#wrapper {
background-color: Wheat;
width: 1280px;
}   
header {

width: 100%;
height: 215px;
background-color: White;
}
header #background-image {
background-image: url("http://arielbalter.com/cio/img/3tab_slanted.jpg");
height: 215px;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
opacity: 0.3;
position: absolute;

}
#header-group {
margin: 0 auto;


}
#house-logo {

float: left;
height: 160px;
padding-left: 30%;    
}
#line1 {

padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family:"KGLoveSomebody", "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
font-size: 7em;
color: FireBrick;
}
#line2 {


display:inline;
font-family:"Trebuchet", sans-serif;
font-size: 3.7em;
}
```

NOTE: that it isn't perfectly fitted to the code you provided. I had to extend the height of the header to 215px to fit the "line2" you can try and fiddle with line 2 css if you need to have a smaller height size.

Comment: I took out all the positions you don't need them. I used padding the fix it and display table I can't see the rest of your code so I don't know if that will fit in.

Comment: It does work, but not quite what I wanted.  I really want to keep the group together as a unit and center the header-group.  Seems like it should be possible.

Comment: I made it another way maybe this will be better for you. Note that I had to extend the height of the header and background image to fit line2 in the background because line2 won't move up. So thats for you to figure out if you don't like this

Comment: Why Vote down the answer and not provide another solution?